# How can we use ImageJ application with Python 3.7 for for automating Image processing...?

Tags: python, image-processing, jython, imagej

I'm trying to open and give commands to 'imageJ' image-processing tool from python3.7 with the OS and subprocess modules. I'm only able to open the 'imageJ' application but unable to give any further commands like "Import-Image sequence, process-enhance contrast, etc." to it. Actually I need to automate the image processing to a large number of Image stacks. will be really helpful if someone can give provide something related to this.

I'm using this

```
from os import*               
import subprocess as sp  
startfile("E:\ImageJ\ImageJ.exe")  
sp.call(Image Sequence...,"open=i:\\imajeJ_test\\TR44_3mps_T1_TSR04_C1_10i - Copy\\150_3.26C1_0001.tif file=C1 sort");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why ImageJ from Python? Why not do the processing directly in Python? Also, this might be easier if you make an ImageJ script, and run that (see [here](https://imagej.net/Scripting_Headless)).

Comment: Apparently you can even script ImageJ [using Python](https://imagej.net/Jython_Scripting)!